# Laravel migration reset fails

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

I have made some migration files in Laravel. When I type `php artisan migrate` 
in my terminal, everything goes fine. If I want to rollback all the migrations, I type `php artian migrate:refresh`, and I get an error:

```
[ErrorException]                                                             
include(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api-dashboardv2/app/database/ 
migrations/2014_10_03_113254_create_groups_user_table.php): failed to open
stream: No such file or directory.
```

The name if the file was `2014_10_03_113254_create_groups_user_table.php` but I changed it to `2014_10_03_113254_create_group_user_table.php`(without the 's' by group).

After I changed the filename, I removed my database manually and created al the tables again, with the migration files.

I do not understand why I still get this error.

Comment: did you try `composer dump`? Might need to reload the files

Comment: And did you delete the entire table, including the migrations table?

Comment: Yes, I deleted the entire database, including the migrations table. But, composer dump did work! Thank you ;)

Comment: Cool - I've posted it as an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `composer dump`? Might need to reload the files since you changed the migration files.